# From postfix to expression-tree algorithm (with function call)

Tags: function, tree, expression

After reviewing all related entries in Stackoveflow and also after googleing a lot, I can not find the algorithm I need.

Having expressions similar to this one (in postfix notation):

```
"This is a string" 1 2 * 4.2 ceil mid "is i" ==
```

I need an algorithm that transforms it into an Expression Tree.
I've found many places that explain how this transformation can be done, but they only use operators (+,-,*, &&, ||, etc). I can not find how to do it when functions (with zero or more arguments) are involved, like in the example above.

**Just for clarity**, the postfix expression above will look as follows when using infix notation:

```
mid( "This is a string", 1*2, ceil( 4.2 ) ) == "is i"
```

A general algorithm in pseudo-code or Java or JavaScript or C would be very much appreciated (please keep this in mind: from **postfix** to expression-tree).

Thanks a million in advance.